# How to Disable Beep Sound in Click Mouse?

Tags: java, swing

How to Disable Beep Sound in Mouse left click?
don't use of any code for sound(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep() or '\007').
but on all over my project play Beep sound When mouse left click.

Comment: Say what ? You get a beep every time you do a left mouse click on a Swing application ? This is not standard behavior, so you must have implemented that yourself. I would suggest to perform a search in your project on the usages of the [`Toolkit#beep()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#beep()) method and remove those

Comment: no one of my three mouse buttons notified me with sound

Comment: might be an Operating System beep if you are clicking something disabled or inactive.

Answer (score 3):

Search for :

`Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep()`
or 
`\007` and remove them.

> Note : You implemented the beep yourself unless you copied someone else's code :)

Comment: +1 for the info and the Note part.  Regards